# Convert Double to specific form

Tags: java, string, double

I have this code below:

`System.out.println(transaction.getAmount());`

that returns the amount in this form: `100.0` (which is `double`).

How can I convert it into this form: `10000` ?

Comment: `System.out.println((int)(transaction.getAmount() * 100));`

Comment: Are you sure you know what you want? 100.0 != 10000

Comment: Do you mean 100.00 ?

Comment: i need to remove the point to use this in my JSON code. basically my system retrieve a value of 100.00=100.00 US$, but i need to put the value as 10000 into this JSON in order for it to read it as 100 US$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply by 100 and get the integer value:

```
 System.out.println(Double.valueOf(transaction.getAmount() * 100).intValue());
```

Another option is to use a `String.format()`

```
double amount = transaction.getAmount();
System.out.println(String.format("%1$,.2f", amount).replace(".", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kocko, this work System.out.println(Double.valueOf(transaction.getAmount() * 100).intValue());

Answer (score 0):

You could use system.out.format and multiply your number by 100:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   double test = 100;
   test = test * 100;
   System.out.format("Here is my number: %.0f", test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
int x;
double y = transaction.getAmount() * 100.00;
x = (int)y;
System.out.println(x);
```

See? You do [explicit type casting](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SCJP/0080__Type-Casting/Implicitandexplicitcasting.htm) to get your result in `int`, because `double` is a larger data-type than `int`.